# Python Nested Loop unique pairs

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a nested loop that prints out all possible "unique pairs" of numbers from a certain range. For example, if the range was from 1 to 3 the unique pairs would be:

(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,3)

If the range was from 1 to 4 the unique pairs would be:

(1,2)
(1,3)
(1,4)
(2,3)
(2,4)
(3,4)

Here's how I did it for 1 to 3:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(2,4):
        if (i != j & j != (i-1)):
            print (i,j)
```

which prints out (1, 2), (1, 3),(2, 3). But this is a hack because it doesn't work when I change the range to 1,5. It prints out duplicate pairs such as (1,5) and (5,1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print list(itertools.combinations(range(1, 5), r=2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

As long as your inputs are unique, there will be no repeated combinations:

> `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)`
>
> Return `r` length subsequences of elements from the input `iterable`.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.
>
> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their
>   value. So if the input elements are unique, **there will be no repeat
>   values in each combination**.

Answer (score 10):

```
for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(i+1,4):  # <-- the key is to make j start at i+1
        print (i,j)
```

Answer (score 6):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
n = 4
x = [(i,j) for i in range(1,n+1) for j in range(i+1, n+1)]
print x
```

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Why `n+1`? Isn't `n+1` just 5? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here?

Comment: You need n+1 because range (i, j) goes from i to j - 1. So if we used (1, n) we would have 1 to n - 1. So if n was 4, then we would be missing 4, we would only have 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: @AlexandruGodri I think he is asking why not replace all `n+1`'s with 5's.

Comment: Because i wrote it for a general purpose. You just change the "n" to whatever and the code works :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `itertools.combinations`:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> print list(combinations(range(1,4), 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

[Python 2 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

[Python 3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Answer (score 4):

See [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module.

Maybe what you want is

```
list(itertools.combinations(range(1,4),2)) == [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```