# Nested Loop counts several times the same values

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dataframe, nested-loops

I am trying to kreate a nested loop to calculate the price combinations between the Car ModelName, e.g.:

> ```
> fact_date     CarID   Country  Type   ManufactureNameSum      Sum_Costs
> 2017-07-14    1       USA      Car    Ford_Focus____VW_Jetta  34003
> ```

which means I have a combination of the **ManufactorName** and **ModelName** and the sum of the **AcquisitionPrice**. Somehow I receive the results twice due to the nested loop but just want to have it once. I was thinking solving it with the following line:

```
row['ManufactureName'] != row2['ManufactureName']
```

but this only solves the problem with the same **ManufactureName** but not the one having due to two lists twice the result.

Hope somehone could help here.

**Adjustment**

**I adjusted the code for the nested loop, but still have the propblem concerning the fact_date indexing as I had before.**

***Adjusted Code***:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Sales_Cars.csv', encoding='cp1252', sep=';', index_col=0).dropna()
df2 = pd.DataFrame([])
for current_date in df.index.unique():
    for i in range(0, len(df)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
            if (
                    df.iloc[i]['ManufactureName'] != df.iloc[j]['ManufactureName'] and
                    df.iloc[i]['CarID'] == df.iloc[j]['CarID'] and
                    df.iloc[i]['Country'] == df.iloc[j]['Country']):
                df2 = df2.append(
                    pd.DataFrame({
                        'CarID': df.iloc[i]['CarID'],
                        'Country': df.iloc[i]['Country'],
                        'Type': df.iloc[i]['Type'],
                        'ManufactureNameSum': (
                            df.iloc[i]['ManufactureName'] +
                            '_' +
                            df.iloc[i]['ModelName'] +
                            '____' +
                            df.iloc[j]['ManufactureName'] +
                            '_'+df.iloc[j]['ModelName']
                        ),
                        'Sum_Costs': (
                            df.iloc[i]['AcquisitionPrice'] +
                            df.iloc[j]['AcquisitionPrice']
                        )
                    }, index=[0]), ignore_index=True) 
print(df2)
```

The data looks like the following:

> ```
> fact_date CarID   ManufactureName ModelName    Type   Country AcquisitionPrice
> 2017-07-14    1   Ford            Focus        Car    USA 11640
> 2017-07-14    2   Ford            Mustang      Car    USA 12994
> 2017-07-14    3   Ford            Fiesta       Car    USA 12842
> 2017-07-14    4   Ford            Mondeo       Car    USA 14685
> 2017-07-14    1   VW              Jetta        Car    USA 22363
> 2017-07-14    2   VW              Polo         Car    USA 20107
> 2017-07-14    3   VW              Golf         Car    USA 21256
> 2017-07-14    4   VW              Parteon      Car    USA 23679
> 2017-07-14    1   Toyota          Prius        Car    USA 14384
> 2017-07-14    2   Toyota          Avensis      Car    USA 14821
> 2017-07-14    3   Toyota          Corolla      Car    USA 12480
> 2017-07-14    4   Toyota          Land Cruiser Car    USA 11502
> 2017-07-14    1   BMW             1er          Car    USA 35127
> 2017-07-14    2   BMW             2er          Car    USA 43924
> 2017-07-14    3   BMW             3er          Car    USA 40573
> 2017-07-14    4   BMW             4er          Car    USA 36690
> 2017-07-14    1   Mercedes        C-Klasse     Car    USA 36646
> 2017-07-14    2   Mercedes        A-Klasse     Car    USA 40912
> 2017-07-14    3   Mercedes        B-Klasse     Car    USA 39060
> 2017-07-14    4   Mercedes        E-Klasse     Car    USA 41838
> ```

Comment: Use ` itertools.combinations` to generate the unique pairs of indices to iterate over

Comment: @kevinkayaks, do you have an example based on my problem? Is it not possible via nested loop?

Comment: If you're set on the double loop, you should start the second loop at the value of the index in the first loop I think. Consider this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324025/python-nested-loop-unique-pairs

Comment: But I would generate the required index pairs with `itertools.combinations` and use one loop, personally

Comment: @kevinkayaks, good point starting in the second loop the index like i+1. How could I perfomr it in my example?

Comment: Instead of using `df.iterrows()` to set up your iterator I would use `for i,j in itertools.combinations(range(n),2)` where `n` is the number of columns in your dataframe. Then `row = df.iloc(i)` and `row2= df.iloc(j)` I think. I don't really know pandas.

Comment: You could also use `iloc` with the double loop approach. Nothing requires you to use `df.iterrows()`

Comment: I meant rows, not columns.

Comment: @kevinkayaks,  thanks, the only problem I see is the indexing on the fact_date. How can I achieve that using still the nested loops?

Comment: Extract the date column and you can index into that too with I and j

Comment: @kevinkayaks, Could you show it based on the new code I added? And then post it as answer that I can mark it as final answer

Comment: @kevinkayaks, no idea how to solve it?